# p6spy cannot find a suitable driver for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, p6spy

using tomcat 7, tomcat-jdbc.jar, p6spy 2.14, C3p0, and hibernate on ubuntu 14.04 OS.

my p6spy.jar resides in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib which is in my cp. spy.properties file is being passed in via system property to tomcat properly.

Relevant section of hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-config>
      <driver_class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</driver_class>
      <url>jdbc:p6spy:mysql://myhost:3306/mydatabase</url>
      <username>xxx</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
</hibernate-config>
```

when i explicitly add
    driverlist=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

to the spy.properties tomcat throws this exception:

```
Warning: Error registering driver names: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6DriverNotFoundError: Error registering driver names: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ModuleManager.loadDriversExplicitly(P6ModuleManager.java:220)
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ModuleManager.<init>(P6ModuleManager.java:130)
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ModuleManager.initMe(P6ModuleManager.java:73)
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ModuleManager.<clinit>(P6ModuleManager.java:61)...
```

When i rem out the driverlist setting - or put it in like above i always get this exception - oddly lloking like the p6spy prefix was truncated off my connection string:

```
WARN [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool]: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@309efc1f -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to find a driver that accepts jdbc:mysql://devtestrds.cdsug1b8degu.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/biz_eng
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver.findPassthru(P6SpyDriver.java:119)
        at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver.connect(P6SpyDriver.java:94)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

im at a loss as to why p6spy wont find this driver. Could this be some kind of class loading error perhaps? any clues appreciated

Comment: You need to add the MySQL Connector/J driver to the classpath of your application (either in the tomcat libs folder or in the WEB-INF/libs folder of your application)

Comment: thanks @MarkRotteveel missing the Connector/J was part of the problem. After adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar i ended up with a linkage error but tomcat DID find a "suitable driver" so +1.

Answer (score 2):

With P6Spy 2.X, you will need to set driverlist=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in spy.properties.

P6Spy 1.3 would automatically register drivers which sometimes caused duplicate registration. This is why 1.3 also had the setting to deregister drivers.

Answer (score 0):

After adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar to my CP i was able to get tomcat to find a sql driver via the p6spy driver passthrough - but then i ended up throwing a linkage exception.

I did eventually however get p6spy running correctly on my tomcat7/hibernate config by downgrading to p6spy v1.3 and setting "deregisterdrivers=true" in the corresponding 1.3 format spy.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Going crazy today while facing this issue.
Scrolling up my log, I realize that my **ojdbc driver was not supported by Java 6**. Configuring Java 7 and everything goes well.